# addEventListener('click') is executing on its own

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

In my javascript (ES6), I have a simple `<a>` tag with an event handler, basically when the `<a>` tag is clicked I want the page to redirect.

My problem is that when I pass the URL parameter to the function that handles the redirect, the test function executes regardless of whether the `addEventListener` has been clicked or not, so it's basically just redirecting back and forth on its own on page load which is not what I want.

Is there any reason `this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.test(this.elem.id), false);` is executing on its own?

index.html:

```
<a id="about" class="a-tag" target='_blank'>About</a>
```

about.html:

```
<a id="index" class="a-tag" target='_blank'>Index</a>
```

Master.js:

```
import { Nav } from 'module/Nav';

(function() {

  Nav.init();

})();
```

Nav.js:

```
export const Nav = {

  elem: document.querySelector('.a-tag'),

  init() {
    this.render();
  },

  test(page) {
      window.location.href = "/" + page + ".html";
  },

  render() {
    if (this.elem) {
      this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.test(this.elem.id), false);
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: If you're programming in ES6, you don't need `"use strict";`. All ES6 code is strict mode. You also don't need the IIFE.

Comment: for real? many thanks! @torazaburo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't pass the reference of the function, but the result of the function. You call function which redirects directly. Replace with this

```
this.elem.addEventListener('click', () => this.test(this.elem.id), false);
```