# addEventListener Executing Before Being Clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, queryselector

I'm Developing a basic Chrome extension centred around a video game. In order to create the menu I have used HTML and come up with:

```
    <head>
        <title>Inheritance Popup</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:#4d2b88">

        <img
        src= "start_screen.png"
        id='startScreenImage'
        style="z-index: -1;">
        <img
        src= "start_button.png"
        id='startButtonImage'
        style="position:absolute; left:65px; top:145px;">
        <img
        src= "info_button.png"
        id='infoButtonImage'
        style="position:absolute; left:65px; top:295px;">

    </body>
</html>
```

In order to receive input upon the buttons being clicked I am using this:

```
function startGame(){
  console.log("start works")
}
// Add event listeners once the DOM has fully loaded by listening for the
// `DOMContentLoaded` event on the document, and adding your listeners to
// specific elements when it triggers.
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector("#startButtonImage").addEventListener('click', startGame());
  document.querySelector("#infoButtonImage").addEventListener('click', openInfo());
});

function openInfo(){
  console.log("info works")
```

(The above is Javascript)
The only issue is that the functions `startGame()` and  `openInfo()` are executing before the corresponding buttons are clicked. This code was taken from chromes page about content security policy (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) which states that this should work. I also attempted the solution on this post [addEventListener('click') is executing on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114596/addeventlistenerclick-is-executing-on-its-own) but was unsuccessful in adjusting it to my own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call the `startGame` and `openInfo` functions as you do here:

```
document.querySelector("#startButtonImage").addEventListener('click', startGame());
document.querySelector("#infoButtonImage").addEventListener('click', openInfo());
```

Instead do:

```
 document.querySelector("#startButtonImage").addEventListener('click', startGame);
 document.querySelector("#infoButtonImage").addEventListener('click', openInfo);
```

This passes the function itself as a parameter to the `addEventHandler` function, rather than the return value of the function.

Comment: What if ```startGame``` will have parameters? How to pass them if we need to remove the parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass the reference, as second parameter is a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

```js
document.querySelector("#startButtonImage").addEventListener('click', startGame);
document.querySelector("#infoButtonImage").addEventListener('click', openInfo);
```